# How do I overwrite the default 404 not found handler?

Tags: go

Given this sample code

```
package main

import "net/http"

func main() {
    api := http.NewServeMux()

    api.HandleFunc("/test", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    })

    // other routes go here

    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", api)

    // handle err here
}
```

When calling a route that doesn't exist I get a 404 with a message

> 404 page not found

I want to customize this so I added the following **before** calling `ListenAndServe`

```
api.HandleFunc("*", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
    w.Write([]byte("error message goes here"))
})
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, the behaviour is the same as before. How do I respond with a customized not found handler if consumers call a route that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a middleware will check for the registered routes and it can return from there if the route is not registered.

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func routeExistMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // Check if the route exists
        if !routeExists(r.URL.Path) {
            http.NotFound(w, r)
            return
        }

        // Call the next handler in the chain
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

// Dummy function to check if the route exists
func routeExists(path string) bool {
    // Implement your logic here to check if the route exists
    // For simplicity, this example always returns true
    return true
}

func main() {
    // Create a new mux (router)
    mux := http.NewServeMux()

    // Use the routeExistMiddleware for all routes
    mux.Handle("/", routeExistMiddleware(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("Hello, World!"))
    })))

    // Start the server
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", mux)
}
```

Moreover, I prefer using [gofr](https://github.com/gofr-dev/gofr) which by default does all these things by default.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Would you mind explaining why I should add this middleware to each route handler? Because if that handler gets called I already know the route exists, no? So I would need a route handler for called routes that don't exist?

Comment: Middleware are not added for a route handler, it is application/service specific.
And you would need only one middleware for the same.

Check these out

https://gofr.dev/docs/v1/advanced-guide/middleware
https://medium.com/geekculture/learn-go-middlewares-by-examples-da5dc4a3b9aa

Comment: thank you. But what do you think about this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77746156/19698303 Wouldn't that be easier?

Comment: Its one way of doing it, but middleware are much lighter and faster compared to handling it through a route, when you scale your application you can will be able to see the difference and other added advantage of having a middleware

Moreover if you want to add some auth functionality you can do it from the middleware without changing much but in case of route you will need to tweak the code at multiple places.

Comment: maybe I don't understand your sample code. Would you add the middleware to EVERY route handler? If that's the case, why? Because then the router already matched the pattern. If that's not the case, you add this middleware to `"/"` only? And the `"/"` comes first?

Answer (score 1):

Register your 404 handler under `"/"`. `"/"` is the least specific pattern possible and also matches every request, so it is invoked if and only if no other handler matched the request.

```
package main

import (
        "log"
        "net/http"
)

func main() {
        api := http.NewServeMux()

        api.HandleFunc("/test", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
                w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        })

        // other routes go here

        // catch all
        api.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
                w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
                w.Write([]byte("error message goes here"))
        })

        err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", api)
        log.Fatal(err)
}
```

```
$ http :8080/foo
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Length: 23
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 02 Jan 2024 12:41:34 GMT

error message goes here
```

Comment: ah ... so it seems i had to replace the route `"*"` with `"/"` which seems to work... have to play around with it